# Spring-data-mongodb generic type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Let's say we have a simple document type defined in mongodb：

```
{
  _id : OjbectId(xxx),
  value : A
}
```

But the value `A` here could be float, integer, boolean or string. How can I map it into a java entity?

Here's a template which only mapped `_id`:

```
@Document(collection = "my_document")
public class MyDocument {
  @Id
  private String id;

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: OK. Good. Suddenly I understand `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @titogeo said in a comment, you could use `Object` like a generic type as it's the super type of all types.

You can read more about data mapping conversion in
[Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation - Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-chapter).